# Generating random unsigned integers within a range biased toward the middle

Tags: random, rust, normal-distribution

I am trying to generate multiple random u32 integers in a very narrow range. My maximum and minimum both vary between 1 and 6 really. I would like to bias the generator towards the middle of the range.

I have [tried using the `Normal` distribution from the `rand_distr` crate](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46fe40621a850812145151397039d337), but it seems to be for floats and unbounded beyond probability, i.e. I want values between 2 and 5 but I can potentially get a result like 0.81 or 6.92 even if they are rather rare. I wasn't able to find an integer version of the `Normal` distribution in the documentation. I am assuming it does not exist.

I would also like this to be efficient so I have a feeling the normal distribution for floats would not be very performant. I've also noticed a distribution called weighted indexes but this would require manual computation of weights with every iteration.

Perhaps the regular `get_range` for integer values can be biased towards the mean arithmetically somehow after the generator runs. Does anyone have any interesting solutions for this?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and write, in one column, the integers `0..99`.  In another column write the integers in your distribution, as often as you would like them to occur (eg perhaps write `1` 6 times, `2` 12 times, etc).  Now you have a function to translate a random integer in `[0,100)` to the distribution you want.

Comment: Draw two integers from smaller ranges and sum them? For example, draw one between 1 and 3 and another between 1 and 2 to get a number between 1 and 5 (inclusive).

Comment: Binomial distribution might be what you want? It is bounded, integer-valued, and approximates the normal distribution (in a certain mathematical sense) https://docs.rs/rand_distr/0.2.2/rand_distr/struct.Binomial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a biased random distribution from a sample of values, you can use the [`rand`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/index.html) crate's  [`rand::distributions::weighted::WeightedIndex`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/distributions/weighted/struct.WeightedIndex.html) to have fine grain control over your biasness by defining weights of each item in the sample.

```
use rand::prelude::*;
use rand::distributions::WeightedIndex;

fn main(){

    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    //item value and it's weight increasing till middle and then decreasing till end
    let sample_item = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 3), ('f', 2), ('g', 1)];


    let weight_dist = WeightedIndex::new(sample_item.iter().map(|(_, weight)| weight)).unwrap();

    let mut pool = vec![];

    for _ in 1..100{
        let item = sample_item[weight_dist.sample(&mut rng)];
        pool.push(item.0);
    }
    println!("{:?}", pool.iter().filter(|x| **x == 'a').count());
    println!("{:?}", pool.iter().filter(|x| **x == 'b').count());
    println!("{:?}", pool.iter().filter(|x| **x == 'c').count());
    println!("{:?}", pool.iter().filter(|x| **x == 'd').count());
    println!("{:?}", pool.iter().filter(|x| **x == 'e').count());
    println!("{:?}", pool.iter().filter(|x| **x == 'f').count());
}
```

You can try out the code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28931096e5782a127ad08c8ad5885918)

Answer (score 2):

A crude solution: take 2 numbers from a uniform distribution over the interval and use the average.

It will give a distrubution like this: _/\_

For more finegrained control, you need some stepwise interpolation.